# How can I preserve initial value using ngModel in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to add a feature for in line editing.

Here's my html:

```
  <div class="value" data-ng-repeat='value in aaVM.archValues'>
    <div class="nameContainer">
      <div class='name' data-ng-hide='editing' data-ng-click='editing = !editing'>
        <span>{{value.name}}</span>
        <div class="icon">
          <md-icon class="mdIcon" md-svg-src="./resources/images/icons/edit.svg"></md-icon>
        </div>
      </div>
      <form data-ng-submit='aaVM.updateName(value.name); editing= !editing' data-ng-show='editing'>
        <input type="text" data-ng-model='value.name'>
        <div class="cancel" data-ng-click='editing = !editing'>X</div>
        <input type="submit">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Everything works. Here's the issue, because I'm using `ng-model` to bind the values name in the form, When I hit cancel, the ui will present the edited version of the input(assuming edits were made) despite hitting the cancel button.

I want the user to be able to edit freely, and upon hitting the cancel button, it revert the value back to the original value of `value.name`.

I could use a different variable, but I want the initial value of the input to be the value from the `ng-repeat`. Is there a way to temporarily clone the value and retrieve it later in the scope of an `ng-repeat`. Or any other work around to enable to cancel button in the way I've described? Thanks.

Comment: you could use `angular.copy` to copy your model object(`value`) and use the copy with your `ng-model`s.

Comment: On page load store all of your `aaVM.archValues` data. Call a function when cancelling that will restore those values: `data-ng-click='editing = !editing; resetData();'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In **Angular**, Use **directive** **ngModelOptions** to change **ng-model** value on submit **event** and use **$rollbackViewValue** to roll back input original value

**Try this:**

```
<form data-ng-submit='aaVM.updateName(value.name); editing= !editing' data-ng-show='editing'>
    <input type="text" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'submit' }" data-ng-model='value.name'>
    <div class="cancel" data-ng-click="editing = !editing; value.name.$rollbackViewValue();">X</div>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

[**Official Documentation**](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.14/docs/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions) for more information